# Setting ndarray values with the flat iterator

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to understand why the flat iterator of an ndarray works as it does. Let `A` be an ndarray, of shape `(N, N)`, say.

```
A.flat[::N + 1] = 1
```

set the diagonal elements of `A` to the value `1`. So `A.flat` acts, in this way, like a view onto `A`. Surprisingly, though,

```
A.flat[::N + 1][1:] = 1
```

does not modify `A` (as it would if A.flat were a view).

`A.flat` is a `flatiter` object rather than a view onto `A`. What's the rationale behind this? Would it be possible to implement it as a view?

[As I understand it, the raw array data is stored separately from the information concerning the interpretation of that data -- array length, array dimensions, stride, column order, etc.. So it seems the flattening could be achieved by setting the appropriate dimension (and stride, dependent on the column order).]

Comment: If you check `.flags`of those two. You can see that the second one don't own it's own data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, `A[a][b] = B` gets translated roughly to:

```
tmp = A[a]
tmp[b] = B
```

This works fine for python objects, ie list of list or list of dict, but it's problematic for numpy arrays. It works with numpy arrays when `A[a]` is a view of `A`, but doesn't work when `A[a]` is copy. [This page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) will tell you a little more about when indexing a numpy array will return a view and when it'll return a copy. I believe indexing the `flat` attribute always returns a copy. That being said I would just avoid two sets of `[]` on the left side the `=` when you're using numpy arrays.

update:
The answer to your question, "would it be possible to implement [the flat attribute] as a view?" is no. Numpy arrays support arbitrary strides, and for many stride combinations it is not possible to create a 1d view of the flat array. When possible, the ravel method will return a view of an array. It will return a copy when it is not possible to flatten the array as a view. I guess if you knew for sure your array could be flattened with a view you could do something like:

```
A.ravel()[::N + 1][1:] = 1
```